# MySQL query for checking if one date is close to current date

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have two columns(**date field, time field**) which are storing `date` and `time` in string and first step is to combine these two fields so i can compare them with current date(i'm not sure if i'm doing that right). Second step is writing query which should select records only if obtained date from these two columns is close to current date. And that date should be between current date and 4 hours before current date because after that something will happen with all those records if some conditions are not met.

Format of columns date and time:

```
event_date = 'yyyy/MM/dd'             
event_time = 'HH:mm'
```

So here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `events` 
WHERE DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 4 HOUR )
< ADDTIME( event_date, event_time )
```

Maybe i should firstly convert these strings to date and then work with them or something else? All in all if i have some data with these dates for example:

```
1. 2017-02-26 10:00                              
2. 2017-02-26 11:00
3. 2017-02-27 10:00
```

And current datetime is: `2017-02-26 06:00`
. In this case i would get only `1 record` and when one hour pass or `2017-02-26 07:00` then i will get `2 records`

Comment: (Seriously) consider storing date and time as a single entity - and using a datetime data type

Comment: I will. And for example if i have one column with datetime data type i would need to use BETWEEN function for achieving results i'm looking for?

Comment: Once you have sorted out your datetime column, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `event_date` is the date of the event and `event_time` is the time, you could combine them using the timestamp mysql function:

```
select event_date, event_time, timestamp(event_date, event_time)
from events;
```

but it's usually a good idea to actually store the date and time information in a single field e.g. `event_datetime`

you can then write your query like this:

```
select *
from
  events
where
  event_datetime between now() and now() + interval 4 hour;
```

this will return all events starting from now and 4 hours in the future. Or if you want the events from the last 4 hour in the past try with:

```
event_datetime between now() - interval 4 hour and now();
```

Comment: Both answers are useful and good, but i need to pick one, so i think this one is simpler and better.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your date and time to a proper datetime data type. That said, you can do something like the following to accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM `events`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(event_date,' ',event_time), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i') 
   BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
```

The query will return all rows between now and 4 hours from now.

UPDATE: I just noticed the answer from @fthiella, using timestamp probably gives better performance than the example I provided.